# Как подружить Google Search Console и Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud, sitemap, google-search-console

Есть карта сайта. Она хранится в Google Cloud Storage со всеми файлами.

Как ее добавить в Google Search Console сайту?

Вопрос простой, но я не смог ничего найти по нему. Помогите, пожалуйста...

Answer (score 0):

Лучшее решение - это установка/хранение файла sitemap в корне вашего веб-сайта. Возможные альтернативы:

- **[Официальный блог Вебмастера Гугл](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/01/sitemaps-faqs.html)**, сообщает:

> : Где я могу разместить свой Sitemap? Должно ли это быть в корне моего сайта?
>   Ответ: Недавно мы включили перекрестные передачи Sitemap, что означает, что вы можете разместить свой Sitemap практически в любом месте, ***если в вашей учетной записи инструментов для веб-мастеров указаны следующие сайты***: 
>    * ***сайт, на котором расположен Sitemap***,
>    * ***сайт (сайты), URL-адреса которого указаны в файле Sitemap***.
>   *Обратите внимание, что кросс-материалы могут не работать для поисковых систем, отличных от Google*.

- Справка Гугл **[Как создавать и отправлять файлы Sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=ru)** - см. параграф **Как сделать файл Sitemap доступным для Google**:

  > Предоставить Google доступ к файлу Sitemap можно двумя способами:
  >   *Отправить его в Google с помощью инструмента Search Console*
  >   ИЛИ
  >   *Вставить в любом месте файла robots.txt строку, указывающую на местоположение файла Sitemap*:Sitemap: http://example.com/adres_sitemap.xml.

Comment: У меня указан путь до карты сайта в Google Cloud Storage в файле robots.txt. Судя по справке гугл - этого достаточно и разницы не имеет. Я все верно понял?

Comment: Я рекомендую вам также использовать Search Console.

Comment: Я его и использую, только сейчас там нет указанной по известным причинам карты сайта. Но в Search Console успешно отображается содержимое актуального файла robots.txt, в котором есть ссылка на карту сайта.

Comment: Я рекомендую вам дополнительно указать вебсайт, на котором расположен sitemap, в Google Search Console, как они это рекомендуют: "если в вашей учетной записи инструментов для веб-мастеров указаны следующие сайты: * сайт, на котором расположен Sitemap..."

Comment: Так я же написал с самого начала, что карта сайта лежит в облаке Google. Я же все расписал...